# How to apply linear-gradient to input border?

Tags: css, border, linear-gradients

Is it possible to to apply a linear-gradient color to input border?
I've tried the following:

```
input{
    border: 5pt solid linear-gradient(rgba(0, 25, 50, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 25, 0.5));
}
```

The problem with the code above is that you can't use linear-gradient as a color.
Just clarifying, I don't want to change the input background color, only border color.

JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/o1yhod9t/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot directly add a gradient to the `border` property as the [third parameter only takes a color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border). Instead you would have to use the `border-image` property like in the below snippet.

Note that the [browser support for this property is pretty low](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image) at present. For better browser support, the same could mimicked using `background-image` property.

```css
input {
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.5));
  border-width: 5pt;
  border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much! For the answer and the cross browser compatibility link. That's exactly what I needed! :)

Comment: @BernardoLima: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: How to make border-radius? because `border-radius: 15px;` is not working

Comment: @AlexZab, This link might help you: https://css-tricks.com/gradient-borders-in-css/

Comment: Nope it doesn't work because input is a replaced element so after & before doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I see that the original answer provides no way to set a border radius. You can pull this off with a weird combination of esoteric CSS elements:

```
input {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: double 3px transparent;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), 
                    linear-gradient(to right, orange, yellow);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
}
```

> What this effectively does is create layered gradients. The inner one
> (the bit that fits within the  element) is just white, so it
> doesn't appear to be anything unusual. Then around that, you add the
> actual gradient that you want (this can be as complicated or simple as
> you like).
>
> Finally, you set a transparent border (with the relevant border-radius
> to get your curved corners), before clipping the backgrounds to the
> relevant areas. The first background (the white one) gets clipped to
> the padding-box, which means it takes up all the space of the content
>
> - padding. Then the second background (the one we want as a border) gets clipped to the edge of the border itself.
>
> So our gradient is effectively covered up by a second, white
> background, apart from the border. You can therefore adjust the size
> of the border to whatever thickness you want, and the gradient will
> fill it.

Original source: https://theadhocracy.co.uk/wrote/gradient-borders-with-rounded-corners-on-input-fields

Answer (score 0):

I used tailwind, reference: https://blog.logrocket.com/guide-adding-gradients-tailwind-css/#input-border-gradient

```html
<div class=" h-12 w-full p-0.5 rounded-lg mt-1.5 bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-400 via-pink-600 to-indigo-500">
            <input
              class="p-2 h-full w-full rounded-lg focus:outline-none"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter movie/show"
            />
          </div>
```

[The input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXuBN.png)