# Tailwind CSS gradient focus ring on form input

Tags: tailwind-css

Has anyone managed to create a gradient focus ring on a form text input with TailwindCSS?

I currently have this (What I currently have)

[image: 1]

with a blue focus ring (focus:ring-blue-300). And I'm looking to get a focus ring like the gradient border on this button (What I want).

[image: 2]

Any tips?

Comment: Hi imthomas i recommend this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054514/how-to-apply-linear-gradient-to-input-border

Comment: Thanks for answering @ChrisSchober. 

Do you know if something like that is possible with TailwindCSS?

Comment: Not yet. Use regular css or this plugin https://github.com/cossssmin/tailwindcss-border-gradients